# Want to hide all categories in wordpress but can't find where wp_list_categories() is called

Tags: wordpress, categories

What I want to achieve is to temporary hide (exclude) all the categories on my wordpress site. I know I'm supposed to edit the call to wp_list_categories() by adding "exclude" to it.

However, I can't seem to find where wp_list_categories() is called. The only statement relevant to navigation bar in header.php is:

```
<div id="catmenucontainer">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_id' => 'catmenu', 'theme_location' => 'secondary','fallback_cb'=> 'fallbackmenu2' ) ); ?>
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me find wp_list_categories()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue. It was much simpler than i thought: just navigated to Appearance>Menus in wp-admin and deleted the category links from there!

Answer (score 0):

Can u tel me where exactly where are your categories being displayed..? I meant in Sidebar,header,footer, etc....

Also check for the widgets in your Wordpress admin section, may be there you mite have placed the Categories as a widget... You can directly remove the Categories by dropping it out from the "Widget Area".

Usually wp_list_categories() will be defined in the currently active theme files, depending on where we want our categories should be displayed.

Comment: hi Amit.. thank you for your answer.. However, i managed to figure it.. thanks again